# How to improve Performance with Nested while loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to update the flag as per below link . My logic is exactly like below mentioned logic (in the link) with 2 more nested loops inside the while loop.

[How To check minimum Date in each observation and update flag dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698391/how-to-check-minimum-date-in-each-observation-and-update-flag-dynamically/45702243?noredirect=1#comment78433083_45702243)

However, logic works fine and works smoothly for few rows. I have around 150000 rows (it will be more in future) and this looping is never ending. I checked the display plan and it says sort cost is 322112% and table Scan Cost is 242938%. Each row is looped.
Is there anyway we can make this code run faster ?

Comment: The way you improve performance in nested loops it to **First** un-nest your loops and then **Second** rewrite your query without loops.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to approach it using a recursive [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

test setup:

```
create table t ( ID Int , StartDate Date , EndDate Date , Flag Int ) 
insert into t ( ID , StartDate , EndDate ) Values 
 (1,'2017-01-01','2017-02-01')
,(1,'2017-01-09','2017-01-28')
,(1,'2017-04-01','2017-04-30')
,(1,'2017-04-05','2017-05-20')
,(1,'2017-04-20','2017-06-12')
,(2,'2017-06-02','2017-06-20')
,(2,'2017-06-14','2017-07-31')
,(2,'2017-06-14','2017-07-31')
,(2,'2017-06-19','2017-07-31')
,(2,'2017-06-19','2017-07-31')
,(3,'2017-01-01','2017-02-01')
,(3,'2017-02-01','2017-02-28')
,(3,'2017-04-01','2017-04-30')
,(3,'2017-06-01','2017-05-20')
,(3,'2017-08-01','2017-06-12')
```

query:

```
;with cte as (
  /* anchor = first start date for each id, flag = 1 */
  select t.id, t.startdate, t.enddate, flag=1
  from t
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from t i
    where i.id = t.id
      and i.startdate < t.startdate
    )  
  union all
  /* recursive, get next startdate after 30 days of previous start date
    , increment flag*/
  select s.id, s.startdate, s.enddate, s.flag
  from (
    select t.id, t.startdate, t.enddate, flag=p.flag+1
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by t.id order by t.startdate)
    from t 
      inner join cte p
        on t.id = p.id
       and t.startdate > dateadd(day,30,p.startdate)
    ) s
  where s.rn=1
)
select 
    t.id
  , t.startdate
  , t.enddate
  , x.flag
from t
  cross apply (
    /* get flag for id, startdate from cte */
    select top 1 cte.flag
    from cte
    where cte.id = t.id
      and cte.startdate <= t.startdate
    order by cte.startdate desc
    ) x
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KADM27580

returns:

```
+----+------------+------------+------+
| id | startdate  |  enddate   | flag |
+----+------------+------------+------+
|  1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-01 |    1 |
|  1 | 2017-01-09 | 2017-01-28 |    1 |
|  1 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-30 |    2 |
|  1 | 2017-04-05 | 2017-05-20 |    2 |
|  1 | 2017-04-20 | 2017-06-12 |    2 |
|  2 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-06-20 |    1 |
|  2 | 2017-06-14 | 2017-07-31 |    1 |
|  2 | 2017-06-14 | 2017-07-31 |    1 |
|  2 | 2017-06-19 | 2017-07-31 |    1 |
|  2 | 2017-06-19 | 2017-07-31 |    1 |
|  3 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-01 |    1 |
|  3 | 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-28 |    2 |
|  3 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-30 |    3 |
|  3 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-05-20 |    4 |
|  3 | 2017-08-01 | 2017-06-12 |    5 |
+----+------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: You have 3, 4, 5 in the flag which wasn't in the expected results... how come?

Comment: @scsimon he is assuming (as myself) that the flags need to continue the count (which the related question actually says, but the results show otherwise). Regardless, this is an awesome answer

Comment: @scsimon as best I can tell, it depends on how you interpret this line in the linked question: " and this goes on for same ID till it reaches the last record for same ID". I see it as meaning the process of 30 day windows, and increment the flag by 1 continues until the end of rows for each `Id`. I assume you are reading it as something like: continue using flag_2 for the remaining rows.

Comment: Well I didn't say it wasn't awesome, i've done nothing but UV Zim's answers. Interesting hostility today on this tag.

Comment: @scsimon I do agree that the linked question could definitely use some better sample data and results.

Comment: @scsimon I don't know how can you interpret my comment as hostile, really. Was just an observation about this answer

Comment: I am copying the exact logic I implemented as per my requirement (this is how I want or client want :-)). the base code I used was from the link I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments... think **SET BASED** when dealing with SQL.

```
declare @table table (ID int, StartDate date, EndDate date)
Insert Into @table
(
    ID
    , StartDate
    , EndDate
)
Values
(1,     '2017-01-01',    '2017-02-01'),
(1,     '2017-01-09',    '2017-01-28'),
(1,     '2017-04-01',    '2017-04-30'),
(1,     '2017-04-05',    '2017-05-20'),
(1,     '2017-04-20',    '2017-06-12'),
(2,     '2017-06-02',    '2017-06-20'),
(2,     '2017-06-14',    '2017-07-31'),
(2,     '2017-06-14',    '2017-07-31'),
(2,     '2017-06-19',    '2017-07-31'),
(2,     '2017-06-19',    '2017-07-31')


;with cte as(
select
    t1.ID
    ,t1.StartDate
    ,t1.EndDate
    ,DT = (select min(StartDate) from @table t2  where t2.StartDate > DATEADD(day,30,t1.StartDate))
from
    @table t1),

cte2 as(
select
    ID
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,dense_rank() over (order by isnull(DT,(select max(StartDate) from cte))) as Flag
from
    cte)

select 
    ID
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,case when Flag % 2 = 0 then 2 else Flag % 2 end as Flag
from cte2
```

Comment: I thought that there was an error on the previous question, and the flag should increment every time instead of going from 1 to 2 on and on

Comment: @Lamak i would assume so as well, which would make it easier, but that wasn't what was in the expected results

Comment: I don't think it would make it easier, since I also assumed that the flag needs to keep going to 4, 5, 6.......etc

Comment: Thank you for all your help.. for now I just added index on my order by columns and code is running within 6 minutes . @scsimon. I will surely try your base code instead of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This logic works perfect but I know this definitely can be written in a better way. If you guys have any good alternative method I would be happy to update my code :-)..

```
--drop table #t
    create table #t ( ID Int , StartDate Date , EndDate Date , LoopLogic nvarchar(100) ) 
    insert into #t ( ID , StartDate , EndDate ) Values 
     (1,'2017-01-01','2017-02-01')
    ,(1,'2017-01-09','2017-01-28')
    ,(1,'2017-04-01','2017-04-30')
    ,(1,'2017-04-05','2017-05-20')
    ,(1,'2017-04-20','2017-06-12')
    ,(2,'2017-06-02','2017-06-20')
    ,(2,'2017-06-14','2017-07-31')
    ,(2,'2017-06-14','2017-07-31')
    ,(2,'2017-06-19','2017-07-31')
    ,(2,'2017-06-19','2017-07-31')
    ,(3,'2017-01-01','2017-02-01')
    ,(3,'2017-02-01','2017-02-28')
    ,(3,'2017-04-01','2017-04-30')
    ,(3,'2017-06-01','2017-05-20')
    ,(3,'2017-08-01','2017-06-12')
    --drop table #auth
    select *
    into #auth 
    from #t
    order by ID,StartDate

    Declare
    @LoopLogic As nvarchar(100) = '0'
    ,@Flag As int=0
    ,@StartDate As Date
    ,@LookupDate1 As Date
    ,@LookupDate As Date
    ,@ID As nvarchar(100)
    ,@PrevID As nvarchar(100) = '0'
    ,@DaysDiff As int
    ,@ReauthFlag As int=0;

    --drop table #Temp_SO_Check
    Select
        *
    Into #Temp_SO_Check
    From #auth;

    CREATE  INDEX IDX_C_Users_UserID ON #Temp_SO_Check(ID,StartDate,LoopLogic);


    --Select * From #Temp_SO_Check As tsc  order by auth#,servicedate

    While Exists
    (
        Select Top 1
                   ID
            From    #Temp_SO_Check
            Where   LoopLogic Is Null
    )
    Begin
        Select Top 1
                    @ID = ID
                    , @StartDate = StartDate
            From    #Temp_SO_Check
            Where   LoopLogic Is Null
            Order By
                    ID
                    , StartDate;

    If @PrevID <> @ID
    Begin
            set @Flag=1;
            Set @LoopLogic ='Initial_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50)) ;
            Set @PrevID = @ID;
            set @ReauthFlag=0;
    end 
          else 
    Begin
    if((@LookupDate is not null) and (datediff(day,@LookupDate,@StartDate))<14)-- if the startdate is less than 14 days from lookdate then it is reauth
    Begin       
             Set @LoopLogic ='Re-Auth_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50)) ;
    End
    Else if ((@LookupDate is not null) and (datediff(day,@LookupDate,@StartDate))>14) -- if the startdate is greater than 14 days from lookdate then it is Initial
    Begin
             set @Flag=@Flag+1;
             set @ReauthFlag=0;
             Set @LoopLogic ='Initial_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50));
    End
    End
             Set @LookupDate = DateAdd(Day, 30, @StartDate);
    if( (@LoopLogic like '%Re-Auth_%') and (@LookupDate<>@LookupDate1))
    Begin
             Set @ReauthFlag=@ReauthFlag+1;
             Set @LoopLogic ='Re-Auth_'+Cast(@Flag as nvarchar(50))+'_'+Cast(@ReauthFlag as nvarchar(50)) ;

    End
             set @LookupDate1=@LookupDate;

    Update
            #Temp_SO_Check
            Set
            LoopLogic = @LoopLogic
            Where
            ID = @ID
            And StartDate Between @StartDate
                        And     @LookupDate;

    End;
    select * from #Temp_SO_Check
```